# ancestor-or-self

Tags: xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ROLES>
<ROLE type="A">
    <USER name="w" />
    <USER name="x" />
    <ROLE type="B">
         <USER name="x" />
         <USER name="y" />
     </ROLE>
     <ROLE type="C">
         <USER name="x" />
         <USER name="y" />
          <USER name="z" />
     </ROLE>
</ROLE>
<ROLE type ="D">
 <USER name="w" />
</ROLE>
</ROLES>
```

and I want to find all USER nodes with `name="x"` and which are immediate children of ROLE nodes with attribute "type" equals "C" and their ancestors with `name="x"` (probably by using ancestor-or-self axis).  In this case, the nodeset should
contain two nodes (not three, since the occurrence of x under B should 
not count).

What is the correct XPath expression that would do it? Why doesn't the following expression work?

```
/ROLES//ROLE[@type='C']/USER[@name='x']/ancestor-or-self::USER[@name='x']
```

(this returns only one node, probably the self axis, and not the ancestors)

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Your description of what you want does not match your XML. From your description you should get only one USER node as the occurence of x under A and B do not count (Note that x under A is *not* on the ancestor axis, it's just a sibling of an ancestor node). Could you clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to find all USER nodes with name="x"…

```
//USER[@name = 'x']
```

> …which are immediate children of ROLE nodes with attribute "type" equals "C"…

```
//USER[@name = 'x' and parent::ROLE[@type = 'C']]
```

> …and their ancestors with name="x".

```
?
```

I don't see any ancestors that could possibly have the name="x". What do you mean?

---

EDIT: Ah, I think I understand. What you mean is:

…and their ancestor's children that are `USER`s with the name="x"

```
//USER[@name = 'x' and parent::ROLE[@type = 'C']]/ancestor::ROLE/USER[@name = 'x']
```

---

And now for the question why your XPath doesn't work:

```
/ROLES//ROLE[@type='C']/USER[@name='x']/ancestor-or-self::USER[@name='x']
```

selects

- all `ROLE`s that are descendant of `/ROLES` (`"/ROLES//ROLE"`)…
- …that have `@type='C'` ("/ROLES//ROLE[@type='C']")…
- …of their USER children those that have `@name='x'` (`/USER[@name='x']`)
- …and going from there all `ancestor-or-self::USER`s having `@name='x'`

the last location step breaks it. There are no `USER` ancestors, only `ROLE` ancestors.

Comment: Indeed, none of the USER nodes actually has children.

Comment: Thanks a lot divo. You got it right before my clarification. (Sorry for somewhat ambiguous description)